# Access violation when an object/interface is shared between EXE and a COM DLL

Tags: delphi

When different modules (exe and DLL) have their own copy of an object/interface instance passed between them, the program gives an AV while exiting. In the snippet below, when calls (from EXE and DLL) to ReleaseManager() is commented out , the AV occurs in the **finalization section of GlobalUnit.pas**. Please see the simplified and reproducible code (D-10.3.2) below. Could someone please explain why the code works when calls to ReleaseManager() are kept intact? Am open to hear any other approach to this problem as well.

Shared Interface between EXE and DLL (SharedInft.pas:

```
unit SharedIntf;

interface

type
    IIntfSharing = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{EA5862AA-973E-4CFA-A7AB-84D4A4F38A29}']
    function SetManager(const AManager: IUnknown): HResult; stdcall;
    function ShowUI: HResult; stdcall;
  end;

    IManager = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{6C408BB1-7CC8-4E71-B3E7-19508045E71C}']
    function ManageSomething(const AResource: widestring): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

    ISecurity = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{0ED8E0BB-F2B3-46D8-8D07-411D71559508}']
    function SecureSomething(const ALogin: widestring): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

const
  Class_IntfSharing: TGUID = '{B9187923-8B2E-469A-B5B4-1D67BA6C1D1F}';
```

Global unit for all the modules:

```
unit GlobalUnit;

interface

uses SharedIntf;

procedure SetManager(AManager: IManager);
procedure ReleaseManager;

implementation

var
  ContainerControl: IManager;
  SecurityControl: ISecurity;

procedure SetManager(AManager: IManager);
begin
  ContainerControl := AManager;
  SecurityControl := AManager as ISecurity;
end;

procedure ReleaseManager;
begin
  ContainerControl := nil;
  SecurityControl := nil;
end;

initialization

finalization
  if Assigned(ContainerControl) then
    ContainerControl := nil;
  if Assigned (SecurityControl) then
    SecurityControl := nil;
end.
```

COM DLL Code that implements IIntfSharing

```
unit DLLMain;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, StdVcl, SharedIntf, GlobalUnit;

type
  TIntfSharing = class(TComObject, IIntfSharing)
  protected
    function SetManager(const AManager: IUnknown): HResult; stdcall;
    function ShowUI: HResult; stdcall;
  public
    Destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ, DLLUI;

destructor TIntfSharing.Destroy;
begin
  GlobalUnit.ReleaseManager; // AV, if not called
  inherited;
end;

function TIntfSharing.SetManager(const AManager: IUnknown): HResult;
begin
  GlobalUnit.SetManager(AManager as IManager);
end;

function TIntfSharing.ShowUI: HResult;
begin
  with TDLLFrm.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TIntfSharing, Class_IntfSharing,
    'IntfSharing', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

EXE code, that calls a COM DLL and also implements IManager and ISecurity

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, SharedIntf, GlobalUnit,
  ComObj, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TController = Class(TCustomPanel, IManager, ISecurity)
  public
    {IManager}
    function ManageSomething(const AResource: widestring): HResult; stdcall;
    {ISecurity}
    function SecureSomething(const ALogin: widestring): HResult; stdcall;

    destructor Destroy; override;
  End;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FController: TController;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TController }

destructor TController.Destroy;
begin
  inherited; // Just to make sure the object is being destroyed
end;

function TController.ManageSomething(const AResource: widestring): HResult;
begin
  //
end;

function TController.SecureSomething(const ALogin: widestring): HResult;
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lDLLIntf: IIntfSharing;
begin
  FController := TController.Create(Self);  // Will be destroyed when form gets destroyed
  GlobalUnit.SetManager(FController as IManager);

  lDLLIntf := CreateComObject(Class_IntfSharing) as IIntfSharing;
  lDLLIntf.SetManager(FController);   // passed over to DLL
  lDLLIntf.ShowUI;

  FController.Color := clGreen;
  FController.Parent := Self;
  FController.Refresh;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalUnit.ReleaseManager; // AV, if not called
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting an interface to nil implicitly call the object _Release function. I believe the problem here occurs because the underlying object was destroyed before the finalization of your global unit. (in this case, in your form's destruction).

If I am right, (I didn't debug your code...) changing to `TController.Create(nil)` would probably fix the access violation, but might cause a memory leak if your interface isn't reference counted.

Calling `ReleaseManager` in `FormDestroy` sets the interface pointer to nil before your TController is destroyed by the form, therefore there is no access violation when `release` get called.